# Can I pass properties of a contained object without having to handle each one?

Tags: .net, class, properties

Take these classes as an example:

```
Public Class ClsA
    Public Property l As Integer
    Public Property w As Integer
    Public Property h As Integer
End Class


Public Class ClsB

    Private Property myClsA As ClsA

    Public Property l As Integer
        Get
            Return myClsA.l
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            myClsA.l = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property w As Integer
        Get
            Return myClsA.w
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            myClsA.w = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property h As Integer
        Get
            Return myClsA.h
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            myClsA.h = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property someOtherProperty As Integer
End Class
```

This means that rather than accessing "l", like this:

```
myClsB.myClsA.l
```

I can simply

```
myClsB.l
```

This does what I want, but I have to pass through each property individually, so as the number of public properties of ClsA increases, the more work it becomes.

Is there any way to pass ALL the properties of a contained object (as if they were the container objects own properties) without having to handle each one individually?

Comment: Not currently, no. Even doing something like using `dynamic` against a DynamicObject implementation would be exponentially more difficult than writing the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inherit From a Base Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973803.aspx)

I think the only way to get what you're after is to do some inheritance. See the above link.

```
Public Class ClsA
    Public Property l As Integer
    Public Property w As Integer
    Public Property h As Integer
End Class


Public Class ClsB
    Inherits ClsA
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim b As ClsB = New ClsB()
b.l = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. This would be a perfect solution to the simplified example I gave. Unfortunately, my actual class already inherits from another. So, I suppose what I am indirectly asking about is multiple inheritance, which I realise does not exist in the .net framework.